# Does android WebView 'goBack' refresh previous URL ? If not how achieve refreshing previous page without losing the URL stack?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview, onbackpressed

Here is my code for onBackPressed

```
 if(webview!!.canGoBack()){
        webview!!.goBack()
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

when on back clicked the previous page is loading but the content not getting updated (not refreshing).
Do we have option to refresh 'on back' in WebView? Or any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
if(webview!!.canGoBack()){
    webview!!.goBack()
    webview!!.reload()
}else{
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: Not working. It reload to current URL, not the previous one.

Comment: @SARATHV It should be working, try putting a debug log in the if statment and see if it even gets called :)