Why android webview goBack always reload/refresh the previous page?
I am using webview in Android app development.
val mWebView: WebView = binding.webview

But when this code is excuted:
mWebView.goBack()

it will back to the previous page, but it always reload this page.
I test on desktop browser, like chrome, it will not reload.
Can anyone tell why this happen on android webview? Thanks a lot.

Because that's the way that webview decided to do it.  There's no right or wrong for either way.  You just have to live with the one they chose (and I wouldn't assume that just because Chrome doesn't do it that other browsers wouldn't.  Not all the world is Chrome.  In addition I would expect that how far in the backstack that is would matter, as the browser won't remember state infinitely).

@Gabe Sechan
But I saw some stackover flow question: say they want goBack and refresh. If it always goBack with refresh, why they ask that question? reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73661365/does-android-webview-goback-refresh-previous-url-if-not-how-achieve-refreshi
